# How to integrate opencv C++ codings with windows application?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, windows-mobile

I have developed hand detection project using opencv C++ in visual studio 2010.
Now I wanted to use those coding to make a windows mobile app. Is that possible?If there are tutorials please be kind enough to provide me.I m new to windows app development.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Open Technologies has done the work to enable OpenCV for Windows Store and Phone apps.  More information can be found here:

https://msopentech.com/blog/2015/03/12/using-cmake-for-building-opencv-libs-for-windows-phone-and-windows-store/